# How do I receive new responses in the Websocket?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

I have a client module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# WS client example

import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect(
            'ws://A.B.C.D:8765') as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send(name)
        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(greeting)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

and the server module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
#!/usr/bin/env python
import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import websockets


import ast
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import datetime
from itertools import chain
import json
import os
import operator
import sys
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

try:
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client["Bubble"]
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

start_match = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    "2018-07-01 18:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

collection = "CRODEN_R16"

async def hello(websocket, path):
    entity_name = await websocket.recv()
    print(entity_name)
    while True:
        file = open("set_start_match.txt", "r")
        for line in file:
            start_today = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                line.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(start_today)
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        diff = now - start_today
        request_match = start_match + diff
        print(diff)
        for post in db[collection].find():
            if "emotion" not in post.keys():
                print("Ignored")
                continue
            if post["timeStamp"] > request_match:
                if post["entity_name"] == entity_name:
                    print("Satisfied")
                    currDict = {}
                    currDict["entity"] = post["entity_name"]
                    currDict["emotion"] = max(
                        post["emotion"].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
                    currDict["profile_image"] = post["userProfile"]
                    currDict["tweet"] = post["tweet"]
                    currDict_json = json.dumps(currDict, default=str)
                    print(currDict["tweet"])
                    await websocket.send(currDict_json)
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    del currDict

try:
    start_server = websockets.serve(hello, '0.0.0.0', 8765)
    print("Start entity server")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Now, the issue is that I want to send name as an input only once and receive the output continuously. 
When I wrote this in client:

```
while True:
   greeting = await.websocket.recv()
   print(greeting)
```

The same response is returned again and again. Even on the server side, where I am printing the rendered results from db, I am printing the same doc.

I am completely clueless as to what is the issue?

Note: I have tried to the run the once-run client module and there I was getting perfect results. It was just that I had to give the same input again and again. I want it to be automated.

Comment: create minimal working example with your problem - without database and other things which we can't have - and then we can run, see problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data continuously someone has to send data continuously.

If someone sends data continuously then someone else has to get data continuously.

So both sides need loop.

client - it sends numbers continuously in loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import asyncio
import websockets
import time

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect(
            'ws://localhost:8769') as websocket:

        name = input("What's your name? ")
        await websocket.send(name)

        i = 0
        while True:
            print('send:', i)

            await websocket.send(str(i))

            time.sleep(2)
            i += 1

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('KeyboardInterrupt')
```

server - it receives numbers continuously in loop

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def hello(websocket, path):
    entity_name = await websocket.recv()
    print('name:', entity_name)

    while True:

       data = await websocket.recv()

       print('recv:', data)


try:
    print("Start entity server")
    start_server = websockets.serve(hello, '0.0.0.0', 8769)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt: # keyboard need special except
    print("KeyboardInterrupt")
    start_server.ws_server.close() # solutin for [Errno 98]
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```